# Getting "Exception: You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream" while working with DRF and django-revproxy

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using [django-revproxy](https://github.com/TracyWebTech/django-revproxy) and [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) in my project. And I'm exposing an API where users get analytics about their chatbots, and it works as the following:

- The user send requests the analytics from the Django project
- Django project, checks if the user is authenticated and owns that chatbot
- `if True` it contacts another external service.

My **urls.py**:

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = (
    url(r'^analytics/(?P<path>.*)$', api.AnalyticsFunctionsProxyView.as_view()),
)
```

And in my view:

```
# views.py
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework_jwt.authentication import JSONWebTokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from revproxy.views import ProxyView
from .permissions import HasChatBotPermission

...

class AnalyticsFunctionsProxyView(ProxyView):
    upstream = settings.ANALYTICS_FAAS_URL

    def parse_body(self, request):
        if isinstance(request, rest_framework.request.Request):
            return request.data
        return super(AnalyticsFunctionsProxyView, self).parse_body(request)

    @classmethod
    def as_view(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        view = super(AnalyticsFunctionsProxyView, cls).as_view(*args, **kwargs)
        view = permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, HasChatBotPermission,))(view)
        view = authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication, JSONWebTokenAuthentication])(view)
        view = api_view(['GET', 'POST'])(view)


 return view
```

And my `HasChatBotPermission` permissions

```
#permissions.py
class HasChatBotPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        try:
            bot_name = request.data.get('name')
            user = request.user
            self.message = 'Permission denied for {}'.format(name)
            return ChatBot.objects.filter(user=user, project_name=project_id).exists()
        except Exception:
            self.message = 'Permission denied, no project_id was defined!'
            return False
```

---

When the view is called it raises this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fcmam5/dela3a/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py", line 379, in __getattribute__
    return super(Request, self).__getattribute__(attr)
AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'body'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fcmam5/dela3a/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/fcmam5/dela3a/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/fcmam5/dela3a/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/fcmam5/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 52, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/fcmam5/dela3a/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fcmam5/dela3a/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fcmam5/dela3a/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 477, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/fcmam5/dela3a/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 437, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/fcmam5/dela3a/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 474, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fcmam5/dela3a/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 52, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fcmam5/dela3a/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fcmam5/dela3a/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/revproxy/views.py", line 204, in dispatch
    proxy_response = self._created_proxy_response(request, path)
  File "/home/fcmam5/dela3a/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/revproxy/views.py", line 139, in _created_proxy_response
    request_payload = request.body
  File "/home/fcmam5/dela3a/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py", line 383, in __getattribute__
    return getattr(self._request, attr)
  File "/home/fcmam5/dela3a/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 264, in body
    raise RawPostDataException("You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream")
django.http.request.RawPostDataException: You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream
```

---

The issue is caused by this line `bot_name = request.data.get('name')` in my `permissions.py`, when I pass a string directly it passes without any problems.

My question is:

- How can I access the request body without having this error? Why I'm having this error?
- Is there a better solution for checking the user permission with Django revproxy.

*This is my first question in Stackoverflow, sorry if my question is not clea, and for my poor English :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having this error because `django-revproxy` attempts to read the raw request body so it can create a proxy request to the upstream server.

However, with Django's (and WSGI's, and buffering) semantics, this isn't possible once you've accessed the request body as anything *but* a raw stream, which you do when you `request.data.get('name')`. This parses the request body as JSON, HTTP multipart, whatever, depending on DRF's request negotiation configuration, and consumes the stream.

There are two ways you could get around this, as far as I see:

- pass `bot_name` somewhere else than the body; a query string parameter, an HTTP header, part of the URL, for instance, so you don't need to access the body, or
- make the backend request yourself using `requests` instead of reverse-proxying (which is basically the same thing, but with added magic to try and copy the request through as-is).